# Custom CSS on button <a> not working

Tags: css, button

I am having some custom css issues, that I would really appreciate some feedback on.

Here is the link to where I am experiencing the issue:
http://bookemcreative.com/testsite/regal-pocket-cards/

You will notice there is a drop shadow under the "View Products" button/link, which I do not want. I have tried to apply some custom css to this using the firebug inspector, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am still learning css, so would appreciate any feedback. Here is the css I tried:

```
a.button.product_type_grouped {
text-shadow: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Use `text-shadow: none`.

Comment: You already use firebug, so check out the css class that creates this shadow and what happens when you deactivate this attribute.

Comment: It would appear as though you fixed the issue on your site. Don't forget to select an answer as correct so that it may help users in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
a.button.product_type_grouped {
   text-shadow:none !important;
}
```

As `0px` is not a value that `text-shadow` property will be looking, so use `none` instead of `0px`, You can see full documentation of `text-shadow` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow)

Comment: It worked!! Thank you. I didn't think of using "none" as I did use px when applying the text shadow to some of the buttons: 1px 1px 1px #c72c34 !important;

Answer (score 2):

use instead `text-shadow: none` with a more specific rule (since it's better to avoid an unnecessary use of `!important`)

```
#wrapper .button.product_type_grouped  {
   text-shadow: none
}
```

which is more specific than the rule you have previously defined

```
#wrapper .button {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #c72c34;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

0px isn't a valid value.

Try this:

```
    a.button.product_type_grouped {
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }
```